# Is it possible to tell df to use /proc/mounts instead of /etc/mtab?

Tags: proc, df

Installing gentoo in chroot I found that commands like `mount` and `df` doesn't work: they try to read file `/etc/mtab` (which of course is empty).

Can I (for future use) setup or even recompile them so, that they won't read `/etc/mtab`, taking all needed info from `/proc`?

Answer (score 8):

`df` and `mount` are based on `*mntent` (ex  `getmntent`) functions, based on `/etc/mtab` and `/etc/fstab`. You can patch these tools, but you should simply copy or symlink `/proc/mounts` to `/etc/mtab`.

Comment: Indeed: I look at `/etc/mtab` in my archlinux, it is a symlink to `/proc/self/mounts`. Is there any difference between `/proc/self/mounts` and `/proc/mounts`?

Comment: `/proc/self` is a symlink to `/proc/CURPID/`. So if you do an `ls /proc`, it's link to `ls` current PID. And `/proc/mounts` is a symlink to `/proc/self/mounts`. So basicly it's the same file.

Comment: thanks for explanation. If I'd have look at `/proc/mounts`, I wouldn't ask previous question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that: instead, symlink `/proc/mounts` to `/etc/mtab` instead, that solve your problem as well.

And notice that in a chrooted environment, you only need a minimal mount table, i.e `/sys`, `/proc`, `/` etc.

Comment: @Gilles, I think the original answer (before your edit) claims that `/etc/mtab` should be a separate regular file, not just symlink to `/proc/mounts`. AFAIK, it's now deprecated but was true some time ago because there were some applications depending on it. Probably they are still here, because `/etc/mtab` is not a symlink on my Gentoo yet. See discussion here: http://gentoo.2317880.n4.nabble.com/rfc-converting-etc-mtab-to-a-symlink-td270774.html So IMHO the edit should be reverted until we get the truth :)

Comment: @g-v `/etc/mtab` may be either updated by `mount`, or symlinked to `/proc/mounts`. Making a copy from `/proc/mounts` to `/etc/mtab` doesn't make much sense: if you want that, let `mount` update it — but the problem here seems to be that `mount` is not maintaining `/etc/mtab` properly, so making a copy that will go stale is not a good idea.

Comment: @Gilles, making a copy at least *did* make sense some time ago: see https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=477498 and http://marc.info/?l=linux-nilfs&m=138159795211469&w=2 *The second* bug is fixed I think, but since `/etc/mtab` is still *not* a symlink on my one-year-old installation and the first bug above is *not* closed yet, the original answer is useful. It was a hint that before making it a symlink, you should ensure that it will not break anything (in Gentoo).